# how to add another object like the created one

Tags: actionscript-3

How do i add another object like this one without doing all the code again and without displaying it in 2 separate MovieClip Containers?

i have this
BG is a simple square 10px x 10px

```
    private var bg:BG = new BG();
    private var myContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    public function MainClass_Test() {
        createRow_Col();
    }

    private function createRow_Col() {
        var bg:MovieClip = new BG();
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            bg[i] = new BG();
            for (var j:int = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                bg[i][j] = new BG();
                myContainer.addChild(bg[i][j]);
                bg[i][j].x = bg[i][j].width * j + j * 10;
                bg[i][j].y = bg[i][j].height*i + i*10
                ;
            }

        }
        myContainer.x = stage.x 
        myContainer.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - myContainer.height / 2;
        addChildAt(myContainer,0);
    }
```

how do i make a myContainer2  with the same movie clips as the 1st one ,so then i can add it next to the 1st one

`myContainer2.x = myContainer.x + myContainer.width +10`

`myContainer2.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - myContainer2.height / 2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to change `createRow_Col` to take in a container and an `x,y` :

```
private var bg:BG = new BG(); // this is not used as another `bg` is declared in side the function
private var myContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
private var myContainer2:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

public function MainClass_Test() {
    createRow_Col(myContainer, stage.x, stage.stageHeight/2 - myContainer.height/2);
    createRow_col(myContainer2, myContainer.x + myContainer.width + 10);
}

private function createRow_Col(container:MovieClip, x:Number, y:Number) {
    var bg:MovieClip = new BG();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        bg[i] = new BG();
        for (var j:int = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            bg[i][j] = new BG();
            container.addChild(bg[i][j]);
            bg[i][j].x = bg[i][j].width * j + j * 10;
            bg[i][j].y = bg[i][j].height * i + i * 10;
        }

    }
    container.x = x; 
    container.y = y;
    addChildAt(container, 0);
}
```

A better way would be to wrap the functionality in createRow_Col in a class that you derive from MovieClip so you only instantiate 2 instances and add to stage.

Comment: what does `bg[i] = new BG();` mean and why is he doing it? does MovieClip extend Array or what am i missing?

Comment: I am not sure what the type of BG is OP would need to post that class but if it is just a `MovieClip` then `bg[i] = new BG();` wouldn't work.

Comment: so if i have lets say `for (var i:int = 0; i < 5000; i++) {` (like if i have 5 000 elements) will the function run 2 times when i make the myContainer2(10 000times total) ? or it will do it only once for the 2  containers

Comment: well `bg[i] = new BG();` it is a movieClip

Comment: The function will run 2 times. If the loops inside has 5000x5000 iterations then the inner most code will be executed 50,000(25,000 for each time the function is executed) times.

Comment: so there is no way i can make this class just once ,then save it as a bitmap(or bitmapData)/movieClip and use it as many times as i want without doing the function again ?

Comment: If that's what you want then you can save it into a bitmapdata using http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a class for the container? You can then instantiate it as many times as you want with the same properties...

Comment: cause i`m not that into using classes - kinda new to as3

Comment: Maybe you could better explain what you are trying to achieve in those 'for' cycles. The code looks rather confusing... for example line 1: var bg:MovieClip = new BG(); = what is that for? then you create a local variable bg in the function... and then you assign dynamic properties to it? What for?

Comment: well later on i use this single line to manipulate a single box. but to this example it is irrelevent im trying its not important(sorry).So im trying to make a Container of many squares (just for the example  - 9 ,but really they are as many as the stage.stagewidth/square.width - so they can be 100 ).then save this container and make a duplicate of it and then-> move the 1st down and make the second come in the 1st position ,like they are moving

Answer (score 0):

I would make it like this.
Create Background class and put

```
private function createRow_Col()
```

as part of Background.as and call that function when bg is added to stage using

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded) // in Background.as
```

Then in main class
make vars bg1 and bg2, and add the to your container. I would guess that you whant this so you can make some transition effect, if thats not the case, you can just leave it as is and put j < 10 instead of j < 5 in loop.

Hope this will help!

Comment: well yes - i want to moveOut the 1st container and moveIn the 2nd one but classes are a little new to me

Comment: Well, once you get used to it its really simple and your code will be much easier to read and work with it. when you write bg:BG = new BG() you are creating instance of BG class, which is now empty. but what if you create BG.as file same way like you created Main class, and put code in it that handles behavior of that class. That way your main class will stay cleaner and trust me when you start adding features that mess just keeps adding up in your main class and its really hard to change anything without scrolling 3 days. google up "as3 oop"

Comment: i see.well im doing it right now and at first it looks kinda hard.I guess i need to get used to it/this